# Django how to prevent update old user instance?

Tags: django

I am using django signals in my models so I need to be save user in my views. When admin updating any user blog post it's replacing old user author id with admin user. Let you explain little bit. Assume User Jhone create an Blog post and it's pending for admin approval if admin approve the post then author of blog post changing from Jhone to Admin. It's only happening when admin updating post from HTML template. I think it's happing for this line in my views:

```
isinstance.user = self.request.user #it's saving current user id
```

How to prevent updating old user id in my views. here is my **views.py:**

```
def form_valid(self, form):
        isinstance = form.save(commit=False)
        isinstance.user = self.request.user
        status = self.object.is_published
        name = self.object.name[0:20]
        messages.success(self.request, f"{name} comment status {status}")
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

my models.py:

```
class BlogComment(models.model):
    #my fields...... 
   

     def user_comment(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
                comment= instance
                blog = comment.blog
                sender = comment.user
                commnet_notes = comment.rejected_comment_notes
                comment_text = comment.comment
                if sender != blog.author and comment.is_published == "pending":
                   notify = Notifications(blog=blog, sender=sender, user=blog.author,text_preview=comment_text[:250], notification_type="New Comment")
                   notify.save()
    
                if comment.is_published == "published":
                    notify = Notifications(blog=blog, sender=sender, user=blog.author,text_preview=comment_text[:250], notification_type="Comment Approved")
                    notify.save()
                
                if comment.is_published == "published":
                    notify = Notifications(blog=blog, sender=sender, user=blog.author,text_preview=comment_text[:250], notification_type="Notify Author")
                    notify.save()
                
                if comment.is_published == "rejected":
                    notify = Notifications(blog=blog, sender=sender, user=blog.author,text_preview=comment_text[:250],help_notes=commnet_notes, notification_type="Comment Rejected")
                    notify.save()
          
            
          
    post_save.connect(BlogComment.user_comment, sender=BlogComment)
```

How to save old user id in my views for signals?

Comment: Which form is this happening on? The admin approval form? If so, you can just remove the line that changes user to admin.

Comment: I said I need to keep save old user. Currently it's changing user to admin which I don't want